# Instagram OAuth: InternalOAuthError - Failed to fetch user profile

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport.js

I am encountering an issue with Instagram OAuth in my Node.js application. I am using the passport-instagram strategy, and I am getting the following error:

```
InternalOAuthError: failed to fetch user profile
    at /home/icsl-008/work/blackchain-backend/server/node_modules/passport-instagram/lib/strategy.js:80:28
    at passBackControl (/home/icsl-008/work/blackchain-backend/server/node_modules/oauth/lib/oauth2.js:132:9)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/home/icsl-008/work/blackchain-backend/server/node_modules/oauth/lib/oauth2.js:157:7)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:387:35)
    at endReadableNT (internal/streams/readable.js:1317:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:82:21)
```

Here is my relevant code for setting up the Instagram OAuth strategy and handling the authentication:

```
passport.use(
  new InstagramStrategy(
    {
      clientID: "CLIENTID",
      clientSecret: "CLIENTSECRET",
      callbackURL: "https://061d-122-170-109-252.ngrok-free.app/api/auth/instagram/callback",
      scope: ['user_profile'],
    },
    function (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
      console.log("accessToken: " + accessToken);
      console.log("refreshToken: " + refreshToken);
      // Store or use the obtained accessToken
      console.log("profile: " + profile);
      return done(null, profile);
    }
  )
);
```

```
// Callback route after Instagram redirects
app.get('api/auth/instagram/callback',
  passport.authenticate('instagram', { failureRedirect: '/login' }),
  function(req, res) {
    try {
      console.log("instagram redirect", req.query.code)
      // Successful authentication, redirect home.
      res.redirect('/profile');
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("get error: " + error)
    }
 });
```

**Additional Information**:

Passport version: `^0.6.0`
Instagram strategy version: `1.0.0`

**Steps Taken**:
I have verified my Instagram API credentials and checked the documentation, but I still cannot fetch the user profile.

**Expected Behavior:**
I expect the user profile to be fetched successfully after Instagram authentication.

**Any Help Appreciated:**
I would appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue. Thank you!